# Unable to connect to car via Bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth

I recently got a 5th generation iPod touch. I was trying to connect to a car over Bluetooth, but it won't even show up on my iPod (and yes the car's Bluetooth was on). My iPod is on iOS 7.0.4. Any ideas?

Edit: yes, My iPod's Bluetooth was on

Comment: Was your iPod's bluetooth on?

Comment: Consult the documentation for the car bluetooth.  As I recall in my Ford, I had to go through some menus to get the bluetooth into "discoverable" mode.

Answer (score 1):

You need to open both your cars bluetooth settings (there should be something like "pair new device") and your iPod's bluetooth settings.
That way the devices can get paired. This only needs to be done the first time. From then on, the connection should work automatically.